# Citrix client automation

Tags: citrix

I work on a password manager application. I try to integrate it with Citrix systems. I would like to be able to:

- automatically log in to Citrix server from client machine
- retrieve the list of published applications from XenApp
- automatically start published application
- send application specific user and password information to published application

I have searched the web for some kind of API/SDK for such tasks, but I have found nothing.
For now the best option I can find is to use web browser automation to navigate Citrix Web interface, login automatically, retrieve published applications and start them. For sending user and password information to published application I can use Windows messages.

Such solution is possible to implement, but doesn't seem very reliable. Different versions of Citrix have different web functionality. Even configuration changes can make a big difference. Additionally I have found that Citrix sites use a lot of different dynamic redirections internally, mainly Javascript, which makes things even more difficult.

I also tried ICA file generation, but it seems to require the information, which is not available to normal end user. The only information such user usually has is web interface address, login name and password.

Is there a better way of integrating with Citrix web interface?

Answer (score 1):

The Citrix Web Interface consist of two virtual websites, the "html" part that you see as a user and one called "PNAgent" that can be used programmatically.

You can send/receive XML with WebInterface to logon, enumerate resources and start applications. The [.dtd file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_type_definition) can be found on the WebInterface server.

Some resources to get you started:

- [XML Service Explorer](http://www.sepago.de/d/research-development/downloads/xmlserviceexplorer)
- [Scriptable Citrix Password Encoder](http://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2013/03/19/scriptable-citrix-password-encoder/)
- [PowerShell script for testing the Citrix Web Interface](http://www.conoscenza.nl/nl/blog/powershell-script-voor-het-testen-van-de-citrix-web-interface-communicatie) (Dutch)

Please note that the Citrix WebInterface is considered legacy and is replaced by [Citrix StoreFront](http://blogs.citrix.com/2013/09/09/web-interface-or-storefront/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems though, that it doesn't solve my problem. It seems that Citrix XML Service is usually behind a web interface and is not visible on user device. Do I understand it correctly that this automation is not possible over the internet?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to script that with Receiver and Storefront using [Fast Connect SDK](https://www.citrix.com/go/citrix-developer/storefront-receiver-developer-community/store-receiver-other-sdks.html). It should be also possible to make it work for PNA, but not Web Interface.